# Pretty Printing in Mathematica

Tags: output-formatting

I have a list `ep = {I Sqrt[2], {{I, 1/GoldenRatio, Sqrt[2]}, {1, 0, 1}}}` and I want to write a function that will output the list `ep` in the following forms:

[image: OutputFormOverK]

and

[image: OutFormNotOverK]

Playing in the Mathematica Notebook, I did the following:

```
myOutputForm[ep_List] := 
    Module[{ep1, epe, r},
        ep1 = Map[HoldForm[#] &, ep[[2]][[1]]]; 
        epe = Map[HoldForm[#] &, ep[[2]][[2]]];
        r = Apply[Times, MapThread[Power, {ep1, epe}]]
    ];
```

`myOutputForm[ep]` gives this as output

[image: MathematicaOutput]

Which is a bit closer to [image: OutFormNotOverK].

How do I make this function to achieve what I have in

[image: OutputFormOverK]

and

[image: OutFormNotOverK]?

Any suggestion will be much appreciated.

Comment: The simpleset way is using the `Text` cell(shortcut for `Alt+7`), then you can use the shortcup `Ctrl+9` to write your formula. See [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/egpZf.png)

Answer (score 1):

Here are two equivalent suggestions to obtain your first form that are slightly more compact than what you have already:

```
ep[[1]] == Inner[Defer@*Power, Sequence @@ ep[[2]], Times]
ep[[1]] == Times @@ MapThread[Defer@*Power, ep[[2]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

And here is a suggestion for your second format:

```
With[{base = ep[[1]]}, HoldForm@Power[base, k]] ==
 Inner[
   HoldForm@*Power,
   Map[Power[#, k] &, HoldForm /@ ep[[2, 1]]], ep[[2, 2]],
   Times
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

As for the ordering of factors on the right hand side of these expressions, that is the canonical order that *Mathematica* likes. Although that is not what you wrote, hopefully that is not an issue, because trying to change that is probably a hopeless battle.

Comment: the order is not a problem at all. My challenge is actually  making the output exactly the same (up to the ordering) as presented in the images. In particular, I want the parenthesis and the dots also.

Comment: @evansdoe Just to make sure, do you really need to generate this programmatically though? If the format is what you want, could you just type in the formulae exactly as you like them? Could you provide some context as to what you need this for?

Comment: This is the format I want them. Note that I use LaTeX in writing the format of the output. 

    ` ( i \sqrt{2} )^{k}  ==  ( ( i )^{k} )^{1} \cdot ( ( \sqrt{2} )^{k} )^{1} \cdot ( ( \frac{1}{GoldenRation} )^{k} )^{0} ` 

and the second one is as follows 

    ` i \sqrt{2}  ==  ( i )^{1} \cdot ( \sqrt{2} )^{1} \cdot ( \frac{1}{GoldenRation} )^{0} `

I need it for a project I am working on. The objects we treat are viewed differently at each level. In particular we, consider `( i \sqrt{2} )^{k}` as sequences where k runs over a specified range. This is all I can say.

Comment: I have attached a file indicating the exact output format I require. 

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_EVcKlnBFPcNFByVDhRaEUyVVk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @evansdoe the latex format that you  provided here is not in the same order as with the initial question.

Comment: @mahmoh I already stated earlier in one of my comments  that the order is not a problem here. They are the same up to ordering.